# synonym for active databaseconnection

Tags: vb.net, ado

In VB.NET (Visual Studio 2008) I want to scroll through the records of a datatable. I tried like this:

```
Dim cnnNWind As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rstNwind As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Test As String

cnnNWind.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=C:\Users\Vitali\Desktop\aktuelle_Projekte\Berolina\Berolina_EIS\Berolina_EIS\Berolina_EIS\BerolinaDB.sdf"
rstNwind.Open("select Nachname from T_Mitarbeiter", ActiveConnection:=cnnNWind)   ':=cnnNWind
With rstNwind
    Do Until .EOF
        Test = .Fields("Nachname").Value
        MsgBox(Test)
        .MoveNext()
    Loop
End With
rstNwind.Close()
```

Now I get a connection error, must be because there is already a database connection in the form. What is the right term to use the current connection? In Access it can be used `currentproject.connection` is there anything like this?
Name of my database: BerolinaDB.sdf
There also is a tableAdapter for the wanted Table, it is used for a dataview element, the name is: T_MitarbeiterTableAdapter

EDIT: Error Message 
"Die Verbindung kann nicht verwendet werden, um diesen Vorgang auszuführen.  Sie ist entweder geschlossen oder in diesem Zusammenhang ungültig."

Comment: Could you post the exact error message received?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: The error message complains about a connection being closed when you try to execute your command

Comment: yes, but there is already a connection in the form, can I use this connection instead?

Comment: What happen if you add _cnnNWind.Open()_ before opening the Recordset? By the way, do you have a specific reason to use the ADODB classes instead of the native Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 provider?

Comment: that works, thanks. I'm used to ADO from Access, so I thought it would be not so far away to use it in Visual Studio as well

Comment: but with this possibility, I open a new connection, can't I used the connections/tableadapters I already have in the form?

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated (since 2002) ADO classes??? You can use OLEDB providers with ADO.NET.

Comment: @pia-sophie You *could* use the same connection but it´s not worth the trouble you might get. I recommend using a connection as short as possible and close/dispose it after use.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion adding cnnNWind.Open() eliminated the error. For my former question, if the already opened connection could be used I found the solution by trying different things. I can use:

Dataset.Tableadapter.property

Comment: It seems that you should check a tutorial on ADO.NET. ADO was retired over 12 years ago. The *specific database* doens't affect how the commands, connections work either.